# ODataRoute not found

Tags: .net-core, odata

I have this OData route working:

```
[ODataRoute("ClassA/{classAId}/ClassB/{classBId}/ClassC")]
```

But when I add a argument to the end, it is not found any more and returns 404.

```
[ODataRoute("ClassA/{ClassAId}/ClassB/{ClassBId}/ClassC/{classCId}")]
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong? An answer to this question could be verifying the route format and listing requirements for it to work as I clearly am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, found the problem my self. The problem was not the route definition which was perfectly valid. It was the uri I used to query the route.

I was using this formatting for the query: `ClassA("ClassAId")/ClassB("ClassBId")/ClassC("classCId")`

The problem was the type of classCId, it was an integer - not a string. So a type problem can return an odata route not found error.

So, correcting the uri solved the problem:
`ClassA("ClassAId")/ClassB("ClassBId")/ClassC(classCId)`